# Azure WebApp for Containers with random err_name_not_resolved errors

Tags: azure, google-chrome, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

We have an Azure WebApp for Containers.
This system is a SPA web where the frontend periodically checks connectivity to the site backend.

This check is a simple HTTP GET that runs every x minutes.
Sometimes, which seems to be random. there is a `net: err_name_not_resolved` (when using chrome)

Azure reports no issues, nothing strange in our logs. so the error seems to be fully client only.

What can be the cause for this?
Why would a HTTP GET fail to an Azure Website if the site is actually running?

Is it a network issue on our side, or can it be something else.
What can we do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

`net: err_name_not_resolved`  means that the domain name cannot be resolved. In general, It looks like a DNS related issue. The error may be a result of a misconfiguration on your client or router OR the website may be down.

You could try these fixes:

1. Clear your browser cookies
2. Flush and renew DNS. In CMD, run 
    `ipconfig /flushdns`
    `ipconfig /renew`
    `ipconfig /registerdns`
3. Change your DNS address to Google’s public DNS
4. Check your Firewall and Security Software
5. Use a VPN
6. Power cycle your router

For more details, please refer to these blogs below:

https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-err-name-not-resolved-error/

https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-err_name_not_resolved-on-google-chrome/